# I am new to python & trying to understand the difference between class and object

Tags: python, class, object

Is it safe to say in this example: i=1, i is an object and class of this object is integer?

Answer (score 1):

You are completely right. Actually everything with some exceptions in Python is object. Functions and classes are objects. Language contructions (loops, condition instructions) and variables are not. For example:

```
def func():
    pass

print(func)
```

output:

```
<function func at 0x7fb278584280>
```

int is built-in class in Python.

```
print(int)
```

output

```
<class 'int'>
```